# Horizontal Scroll for angular material table with arrow buttons

Tags: angular, horizontal-scrolling, material-table, angular-material-table

I am using angular material table and my table has lot columns to show, i want to implement next and prev button on hover of left and right side of table and on click user can scroll to the end. I am not able to find any such implementation with Angular material table. Please help with any leads. Attaching a picture and link for the reference.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Mobile-friendly-Scrollable-Table-Plugin-For-jQuery-ScrolTable.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library, but you can always make overlay on the sides with position absolute. Then on event click you only need to make something like:

```
this.tableWrapperRef.nativeElement.scrollBy(100, 0)
```

Above one should move 100 pixel to the right (didn't test it).